# remove watermark from PDF file use tools for inspecting and manipulating the structure of pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, adobe-acrobat, watermark

I have a scanned book that was scanned as image. It contains watermark that I want to remove. Here is an example of [page](https://github.com/mediotex/pdf/blob/main/watermark.pdf), that contains minimal text.
I tried to remove that watermark on Windows with Adobe Acrobat XI (version 11.0.23), use Adobe default tools, but Adobe show *"Acrobat cannot find a watermark in this file to remove.If you see a watermark, it was not added in Acrobat or by an Adobe PDFmaker, and cannot be detected as such."*
Additionally, I want to remove yellow background from the pages, make it clean.
Tried dom this with Adobe Acrobat, the same result: *"Acrobat cannot find a background in this file to remove. If you see a background, it was not added in Acrobat or by an Adobe PDFmaker, and cannot be detected as such."* As I can see from GHex editor, the watermark image, seems, was placed by Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows.

So, I want try Linux command line tools/libraries that inspect and manipulate the structure of PDF files. I tried qpdf, but I don't know how to indentify the data stream this watermark belongs to.

```
qpdf --stream-data=uncompress watermark.pdf uncompressed.pdf
```

This [scanwritr](https://www.scanwritr.com) online tool works for me: by applying "contrast" image filter the logo is gone, but it unable process large file (> 80MB), just a few pages, then it hungs up.

Comment: If you own the copyright to the document (or have free use of it), try a trial version of the current Acrobat. V XI is a decade old

Comment: That is a flat raster JPEG image, it is not any kind of layered text that can simply be deleted from the file. Just because it's a PDF doesn't mean it is text, most PDFs are just JPEG images bundled together as pages. Most likely you are going to have to resort to standard image editing tools such as would be found in tools like Photoshop or Paint.NET. Once you have a process you might be able to use batch image processing tools such as [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) to apply the process across the range of extracted images.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate Watermark, you can tell that by the "Bleed Through" from the other side of the scanned page. So the chances are the watermark was in the paper at time of scanning and this is backed up by the high level of colour variation. So 32 indicates it was most likely not an additional overprint.

[image]

IF you simply flood fill with say "White" the edges of the text will be distorted.

[image]

And if you try to reduce number of colours drastically it will be less readable.

[image]

Ideally the "Watermark Removal" should have been attempted at time of scanning at a higher  resolution.

To get a good result would need some text augmentation and then that suggests OCR which is unlikely to be better for this sheet.

However the ScanWriter filter seem highly efficient at balancing the adjustments Hence using a tool like ImageMagic or other graphics app (I was playing with settings in IrfanView) may give the same good result.
[image]